# Show/hide DIV script

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, hide, show

When you click the months on http://kaye.at/test/, the divs show/hide.

When the page loads they are all open, how do I make it so that June is open but the others are closed on pageload?

Or how do I make them all closed on pageload?

JS:

http://kaye.at/test/js/showHide.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('.show_hide').showHide({           
    speed: 1000,    
    easing: '',
    changeText: 0,
    showText: 'View',
    hideText: 'Close'

}); 


});
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv">View</a><br />
 <div id="slidingDiv">
    Fill this space with really interesting content.
 </div>



 <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2">View</a><br />
 <div id="slidingDiv_2">
    Fill this space with really interesting content.
 </div>
```

Comment: `.content { display: none; }`
`#slidingDiv_3 .content { display: block; }`

Answer (score 0):

Select all the containers, exclude the one for June (number 3), hide the rest ?

```
$('[id^="slidingDiv_"]').not('#slidingDiv_3').hide();
```

A better option would be to give them all a class, hide them with CSS and just show the one with the ID `#slidingDiv_3` !

```
<div id="slidingDiv" class="slidingDivs">
    Fill this space with really interesting content.
</div>
```

css:

```
 #slidingDiv_3 {display:block;}
.slidingDivs  {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class where the it has: `display:none;` like this:

```
.class1{
 //your styling
  display:none;
}
```

etc.

this way when you click on it the display: wil be set to `display:block;` ( or what ever your display is )

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to slideToggle them when the document is loaded in the browser.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#slidingDiv').slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing)
      $('#slidingDiv_2').slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing)
    });
```